# Which family of sets is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

Which family of sets is a $\sigma$-algebra?

a) Subsets $X$ of $\mathbb {N}$, for $X$: $X$ is finite or $\mathbb {N} \setminus X$ is finite.

b) At most countable subsets of $\mathbb {Q}$.

c) At most countable subsets of $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Each $\{2n\}$ is finite, but $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{2n\}$ is the set of even numbers, which neither is finite nor is $\Bbb N\setminus(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{2n\})$ the set of odd numbers.

b) Every subset of $\Bbb Q$ is at most countable, since $\Bbb Q$ is countable itself. Then we actually have the power set $\mathcal P(\Bbb Q)$, which is always a $\sigma$-algebra.

c) $\Bbb Q\cap[-1,1]$ is countable but $[-1,1]\setminus(\Bbb Q\cap[-1,1])$ is the set of irrationals in $[-1,1]$, which is uncountable.